# Prototype Pollution in set-value

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I'm on my way to learn Reactjs and looks like it's a pretty severe for me to find a good way to resolve so please help me.

Here's some infor:

```html
"version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

[Prototype Pollution in set-value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzMB6.png)